# Is this a valid factor analysis approach for validating a multi-domain survey?

Tags: factor-analysis, survey, validation

I am developing a new instrument consisting of items grouped into defined domains (constructs), such as personality traits. Each construct is measured through a set of 4-6 items (questions). To validate the instrument, I consider running an exploratory factor analysis (EFA): a) separately for each construct, to assess whether the items are unidimensional, and b) on all the constructs: not across all items, but by combining items of each construct via indexing into a single score, and then running the FA across the resulting approx. 15-20 constructs. This appears more effective then running an FA over all the (approx. 90-110) items, which would also require a much larger sample size?

Is this approach valid? Thoughts?

Comment: This site is much better suited to more specific questions than to questions of, to paraphrase, "here is my approach:  please comment."  I'll be surprised if a topic as complex and multifaceted as this will draw a satisfactory answer, and you may want to contact a consultant/coach/mentor.  But at any rate suppose you tell your N; to what sort of party you will be reporting and with what expectations for scientific rigor; to what degree any of these scales have been previously validated; and whether you are planning to cross-validate.  Cheers ~

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider this a valid approach.  I would recommend reading [Boateng et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6004510/) (selected because it is publicly available, not because it is necessarily a seminal work) and some introductory psychometrics and scale development books. If I were reviewing a new scale I would expect to see item level EFA, CFA, Cronbach's alpha, inter-item correlations, and comparison to an existing measure at a bare minimum. Looking at single factors/sub-scales and then only testing those is not a reasonable shortcut to take.